# Meaning of " whose charges had outgrown her"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> I was introduced to Miss Limplinger, a governess **whose charges had
>   outgrown her**, and who was returning to England. Mrs. Pritchard had made
>   arrangements for Miss Limplinger to share my stateroom on the voyage and
>   to watch over me.

Dose it mean: Because of her responsibilities she seemed older than her real age?

Source: Listening for Lions by
Gloria Whelan

Answer (score 1):

A governess is hired to take care of children. They are her "charges". These charges had reached an age where they didn't need her to take care of them ("they had outgrown her"), so she lost her job.